# RESTSharp: Access values from deserialized class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, restsharp

I am using [RESTSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) to receive and deserialize result from an API call. Response is JSON. I've created a class for the repsonse that looks like this:

```
public class JsonResponseClass
{
    public class Selector
    {
        public static string verb { get; set; }
    }

    public class Points
    {
        public int definition { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

I do following to get the response:

```
var response = client.Execute<JsonResponseClass>(request);
var resData = response.Data;
```

How do I read/print values received from above? For example how do I print values verb and definition from the above deserialized response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to nest the classes. Instead, add a property of each type to the root object's class.

```
public class JsonResponseClass
{
    public Selector selector { get; set; }

    public Points points { get; set; }
}

public class Selector
{
    public static string verb { get; set; }
}

public class Points
{
    public int definition { get; set; }
}
```

With that in place, the code works as expected:

```
var response = client.Execute<JsonResponseClass>(request);
var resData = response.Data;
var verb = resData.selector.verb;
var definition = resData.points.definition;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Sorry to ask trivial question but on recieving side I do this: `var res = funcallthatreturnsresData()`;. I get `nullpointerexception`. What's wrong?

Comment: a nullpointer is just a funny word for a variable that is set to `null`. So basically, you're trying to access a method or property on an uninitialized variable somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what are you asking.

`resData` variable contains data from request stored in `JsonResponseClass` so you need to access it's fields like:

```
string verb = resData.verb;
Console.WriteLine(verb);
```

Comment: `resData.verb` is not valid. Wouldn't compile. Sorry if I am doing anything wrong but I am not able to access these values on receiving end.